# How does Reddit make their log in /sign up modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to replicate a modal similar to Reddit's and I'm not sure how they accomplish the following

1. When the modal is open, scroll is disabled
2. When the window is smaller than the modal, scroll is enabled

I've tried turning on and off some of the CSS properties in the Chrome dev tools, but none of them seem to effect scroll. I have tried adding a scroll disabling function, but the problem with it is that it disabled all scroll, so when the window is smaller than the modal, scroll is still disabled.

Comment: `document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the modal is open, the `<body>` tag is given a class of `modal-open`, which disables the scrollbars of the page itself.

The modal itself is positioned to fill the entire viewport, and is set to `overflow: auto`, which means that scrollbars are only displayed on the modal element when the contents of the modal are larger than the viewport.

You can see a minimal proof of concept below:

```css
/* when modal is closed: */
#body {
  text-align: center; padding: 30px;
}
#body:not(.modal-open) {
  overflow: auto;
}
#body:not(.modal-open) #modal {
  display:none;
}

/* when modal is open: */
#body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#body.modal-open #modal {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
}
#modal_inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body id="body">
  <div style="width: 200%; height: 300%">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('modal-open')">open modal</button>
  </div>
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="modal_inner">
      This is the modal!
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('modal-open')">close modal</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```